# Unicorn publishes all the items under the root Sitecore item after unicorn sync

Tags: publishing, unicorn, publishing-service

When we run the unicorn sync for limited items based on the unicorn configuration's predicate rule then in SPS we noticed that it is publishing all the items under top root `sitecore {11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}`

The auto publish happens after every unicorn sync and we can not disable that `unicorn.autopublish.config`.

**Environment**: SXA with Sitecore 10.3 based on containers

**Unicorn Version**: 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the config file you mentioned there is a setting called `Unicorn.MaxItemsToQueue`

```
<!-- 
    Max number of items that will be processed individually by the publishing code.
    If number of changed items in a sync operation goes > MaxItemsToQueue, a system Smart Publish will be executed instead
    Set this value to 0 if you always want Smart Publish to happen. Set it to something silly (like 1000000) if you never want Smart Publish to happen
-->
<setting name="Unicorn.MaxItemsToQueue" value="1000" />
```

It means that if you sync more items than value of the setting, it will trigger smart publish of the whole site instead of publishing only those items which were synced.

Just change the setting to 1000000 and it will stop auto-publishing the whole site and instead it will only publish what is synced.

And it you don't want auto publish to happen at all, you can disable the file, empty the file and leave only `<sitecore>` node in it or remove `TriggerAutoPublishSyncedItems` processor - whatever is the easiest for you.